# how upload file to my server with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement to upload file to my localhost,with no need for db.i do follow with the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files  but when i run my server,it remind me undefined method `original_filename' for "ftp.txt":String
my view

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true ) do %>
              <%=file_field_tag 'sql_file_name'%> <%end%>
```

my controllers

```
def upload
tmp = params[:sql_file_name]
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', tmp.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
   file.write(tmp.read)
end
```

I can't find the reason why it not works.Looking forward to get your help,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all,How are you handling the attachments/uploads...are you using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip),MOREOVER,your upload method should have POST as HTTP VERB .By this i mean that in your `routes.rb`,you should have something like:-

```
collection {post :upload}
```

assuming,its a new extra restful service in your resource because by default rails provides 7 actions for every resource in routes.rb.

So for :-

```
 resources :places do
    ##new extra call for places/tagged with post request
     collection { post :tagged }
 end
```

i have these routes ready to use - 
notice the /places with POST,Which is by default used for create action after new

```
                      places GET    /places(.:format)                                            places#index
                             POST   /places(.:format)                                            places#create
                   new_place GET    /places/new(.:format)                                        places#new
                  edit_place GET    /places/:id/edit(.:format)                                   places#edit
                       place GET    /places/:id(.:format)                                        places#show
                             PUT    /places/:id(.:format)                                        places#update
                             DELETE /places/:id(.:format)                                        places#destroy
```

Comment: I want to use the simplest way to implement,I didn't use third-party plug-ins,and i have define my 'routes.rb',i am a new Learnner for rails,i have no idea to solve this problem

Comment: Paperclip is a gem to make the work more easy..you can try it out :) ...@ares